# Listing private calendars only - Google v3

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api

This will get me a list of calendars in v3:

' Get the list of calendars
Dim oList As IList(Of CalendarListEntry) = m_Service.CalendarList.List().Execute().Items()

But it give sme a list of all calendars, even the Google ones like "Holidays" or "Birthdays".

In v2 I could do this to just get the users calendar list:

CalendarQuery query = new CalendarQuery();
query.Uri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/owncalendars/full");
CalendarFeed resultFeed = (CalendarFeed)m_Service.Query(query);

I can't find out how to do this with v3.

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim oList As IList(Of CalendarListEntry) = m_Service.CalendarList.List().Execute().Items() For Each oCalendarEntry As Data.CalendarListEntry In oList
If (oCalendarEntry.AccessRole = "owner") Then
    ' Continue
```

Answer (score 0):

In CalendarList: list, add minAccessRole ="owner", which lists only the private calendars of the user(who is the owner of the calendar). It won't display Google ones like "Holidays" or "Birthdays".

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your suggestion. I can't work out how to do that exactly. But what I managed was:

Dim oList As IList(Of CalendarListEntry) = m_Service.CalendarList.List().Execute().Items()
For Each oCalendarEntry As Data.CalendarListEntry In oList
   If (oCalendarEntry.AccessRole = "owner") Then